# Xcode Playground can only run partially

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-protocols

[image]

As shown above, in the Xcode playground, I am trying to extend the protocol *Exercise* to have two more computed properties, *caloriesBurnedPerMinute* and *description*. When I want to run this part of code in the playground, the "play button" at the extreme bottom left corner appears as grey, indicating that it cannot run the code until line 20. However, if I just want to run the code until line 14, as shown below, the "play button" appears as blue, indicating that it can run the code until line 14.

[image]

May I know if there is anything wrong with the second extension of protocol *Exercise*?

edited: the following is the code.

```
import Cocoa

protocol Exercise: CustomStringConvertible {
   var name: String { get }
   var caloriesBurned: Double { get }
   var minutes: Double { get }
}

extension Exercise {
   var caloriesBurnedPerMinute: Double {
       return caloriesBurned / minutes
   }
}

extension Exercise {
   var description: String {
      return "Exercise(\(name), burned \(caloriesBurned) calories in \(minutes) minutes)"
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code into the question. Don’t use images. Pasted code can be copied, pasted and tested.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please Read [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) No buddy will not write your code from images to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, That is just Xcode 10's new feature. See [here](https://peterwitham.com/swift-archives/xcode-10-playgrounds-new-play-system-improve-speed-and-productivity/).

It's a way of running your code line by line, but there are some limitations. If you hover over the line number "20", you will see a grey line:

[image]

That means Xcode can't only run that part of the code, presumably because how Xcode handles extension declarations.

Just add some code that actually runs, as opposed to just declarations, and press the play button above the bottom panel. Your code will run just fine.

Comment: I actually have some code other than the parts shown here, but the problem is that even if I want to run the entire playground, I still cannot make it. I tried to find out the reason why I cannot run the playground, and after several attempts I realise that the problem is with that particular extension on `var description`. Only after I add that extension will I then become unable to run the playground. So I think it is not a problem of running declarations only.

Comment: @qsmy What I am saying is that extensions seem to break this "run only part of your code" feature, regardless what other code you have. If I add a `print("Hello")` line at the bottom, and press the play button above the bottom panel (not the one on the line numbers), it prints "Hello" properly. It's only the "run only part of your code" feature that breaks.

Comment: ok thanks, I got what you mean. I managed to run the entire playground by clicking the button you mentioned, which shows "execute programme", instead of pressing the command+shift+return (what I usually do). So command+shift+return is still considered as a stepwise execution, although it is "run playground", under the editor menu? Also, I have tried to add another property before `description`, and that property can be executed by clicking the play button on the line numbers. Thus it seems like `description` really "breaks" the feature, as you said... Is it a bug or something?

Comment: @qsmy I would say it's a bug. I can't think of any reason why Xcode can't run that whole block of code in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `Double` variables in a `String` cast like `String(caloriesBurned)`:

```
extension Exercise {
   var description: String {
      return "Exercise(\(name), burned \(String(caloriesBurned)) calories in \(String(minutes)) minutes)"
   }
}
```

I don't know why, but it helps